# How to count number of times a certain word occurs in json file using python?

Tags: python, json

I have a json file which have several lines in the file. It looks like this:

```
{"instances": [{"features": [0.0]}, {"features": [0.04]} ]}
{"instances": [{"features": [0.1]}, {"features": [0.09]} ]}
{"instances": [{"features": [0.2]}, {"features": [0.3]} ]}
```

Now, I need to count the number of times the word "instances" occur so that I get the count of lines, in this case 3.

I tried this code but it didn't return anything useful:

```
file_content = str(content_object.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8'))
json_content = json.loads(file_content)
num = sum(1 for line in open(json_content))
print(num)
```

No output printed.

Comment: You just want the count of jsons where `instances` is a key?

Comment: @Tgsmith61591 either count of word "instances" or word "features". It should be the same number.

Comment: Not according to your example. I count 6 `features` and 3 `instances`. Or do you mean the number of lines where either appear?

Comment: @Tgsmith61591 you are right, sorry for that. It should be 3 which is the number of times the word instances occur or number of lines.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's not working because you're just opening the file with `open(json_content)` and you need to traverse it, I'm not sure if you just wanna count the times `instances` word appears or you need something else, you can solve it the first one as follow:

```
with open('CreateFile.txt') as file:
    total = sum(1 for line in file.readlines() if 'instances' in line)
    #total = 3
```

If you needed something else just let me know :) Hope this helps you